# create a dropdown until a certain number + 1

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column that goes from trip 01, trip 02, trip 03... up to trip 50, next to that column there will be an indicator where the current trip is, for example if is in line where is the trip 06, I want to create a helper column that will show trip from 01 up to current trip which is trip 06 and add trip 07 to it, in other words list all previous trips until current one and also next trip. Any thoughts?

I have a spreadsheet where I have been doing tests.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAqaJ2oSYJdVtqTchQalfIS1fU5Qo9foT6RZkO3oTxc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be useful? It lists from A2 to the match of Current Trip +1 within INDEX:

```
={A2:INDEX(A2:A,XMATCH("CURRENT TRIP",B2:B)+1)}
```

[image]